# botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:

Tags: django-rest-framework, boto3, amazon-sns, botocore, python-phonenumber

I use django-rest-sms-auth, which provides such providers as Twilio, Megafon, smsaero. But I've created another provider - Amazon SNS.

```
    def send_amazon_sms(self):
        client = boto3.client('sns', aws_access_key_id=self.conf.SMS_PROVIDER_LOGIN,
                              aws_secret_access_key=self.conf.SMS_PROVIDER_PASSWORD, region_name='eu-north-1')
        client.publish(PhoneNumber=str(self.to), Message=self.message)

    def send_sms(self):
        return self.send_amazon_sms()
//but it returns: 
**botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter PhoneNumber, value: +996550102030, type: <class 'phonenumber_field.phonenumber.PhoneNumber'>, valid types: <class 'str'>**
```

Could you help me, why myphone_num is not correct?
P.S.
when I'm running this locally with my credentials and phone number as a separate python file, everything works fine

Comment: What is `self.to`?

Comment: @Marcin it is a phone_num from my ```@app.task
def send_sms_async(identifier: int):
    code_instance = PhoneCode.objects.filter(pk=identifier).first()
    if code_instance:
        provider_class = get_provider_class()
        provider = provider_class(
            to=code_instance.phone_number, message=code_instance.message, conf=conf
        )

        provider.send_sms()
```